# Inserting into an ordered list in C: use array or linked list?

Tags: c, insertion, insertion-order

When trying to insert into an ordered list, consider the two scenarios.

1. Using an array of pointers. Binary search to find where the
   insertion point is then:

   - Use memmove() to move the bytes to make room for the new address
   - Move the addresses using iteration to make room for the new address
2. Use a linked list and linear search

Which would perform better? My guess is that in optimized code, the two options for 1. would perform about the same but how would 1. and 2. compare. It seems to be that they would both be O(n). Is there an easier way to do this? Would it be possible to set up a binary search on any type of linked list?

Any other suggestions would be greatly welcome.

Comment: linked list insertion time is going to be `O(1)` but if you need an ordered data structure, then you should use a Binary Search Tree.

Comment: Searching would be O(n) though, right?

Comment: Your linked list cache hits will generally be dreadful, btw. The hardware pre-fetcher for #1 is working *for* you. So builds some sound tests and **measure**.

Comment: @JeremyRosenberg yes, searching for singly linked list would be O(n).

Comment: @WhozCraig will do. Should I expect the two options in 1. To perform the similar

Comment: Since I honestly have no idea what you second bullet even *means*, I can't answer that. I know the first one can have surprisingly better performance than you may at first expect (still O(n), but hardware-assisted doesn't hurt). I don't believe the array of *pointers* is needed either, but only you know your data, so *measure*.

Comment: We don't know what type data the user will store, so the pointers are needed. The second option means looping through the list and using a temp place holder to swap the data to the next index to make room for the new data. Thanks for your help